# how to use a scanner's input( used in a swtich case in main's body) in a method('s body) defined outside the main

Tags: java

I am stuck in a code as I have used **scanner** class(system.in) multiple times in a switch case in the **main's** and I have also declared a public method before main, which need to take the argument from that scanner's keyboard input.
how can I access scanner values obtained in **main** method, in a method declared outside the main?

below is a chunk of method's code before the main:

```
public class temp_cnvrter {

public static double cels(double input1)  /* this input1 needs to be fetched from scanner inside main method*/
{
double output1;
output1= input1 + 273.15;
System.out.println("temperature in rankine is:" +output1 );
return output1; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

Comment: you mean passing is as a parameter as in: `cels(scanner.nextDouble());`?

Comment: Call cels() in main passing it the double. Is it really that hard to figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```
public static double cels(double input1)  /* this input1 needs to be fetched from scanner inside main method*/
{
double output1;
output1= input1 + 273.15;
System.out.println("temperature in rankine is:" +output1 );
return output1; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a double value");
    double input = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("you have entered " + input);
    System.out.println(cels(input));
}
```

Comment: @JasmeetSinghSasan I don't see the class. You can post another question if you want. Posting question in comment will limit your question visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the value inside main from another method. All you can do is call the method from main by passing the value as parameter.

The work flow is like the execution starts and ends within the main. You can pass the control to any other methods by calling them. This is the way of doing it.